# why I can't get txtBox2.Text and txtBox3.Text value?

Tags: c#

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl,IRequireGraphicInterface
{  
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      // int i;
        Opcconnect OC = new Opcconnect();
        OC.DataRead();
        txtBox4.Text = "zjy";
    }
}

public partial class Opcconnect : OPCServerClass
{

    public void  DataRead()
    {        
        UserControl1 TxtgetData = new UserControl1();
        try
        {
            TxtgetData.txtBox2.Text = "SJZ";
            TxtgetData.txtBox3.Text ="TEST"

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }
    }


}
```

//I'm beginner, I have tested my program and show noting. I hope get your help how could I get the txtBox2.Text and txtBox3.Text value. thanks.

Comment: What error do you have? We're not psychic I'm afraid :)

Comment: For now, place `UserControl1 TxtgetData = new UserControl1();` in a global space. Just before `public void  DataRead()` to make it a _class level variable_ and try to figure out the reason. Then read [Scope of Variables in C#](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-of-variables-in-c-sharp/)

Answer (score 2):

You've created an instance of `UserControl1`, but you haven't done anything with that instance.  It's not part of any form, it's not displayed to the user, etc.  You are successfully setting the values, but never showing those values to the user.  Because that instance has nothing to do with any other instance, such as the one you're currently seeing on your screen.

Take a step back.  Your `Opcconnect` class should not be trying to directly set UI controls anyway.  It should simply return the data needed by the UI, and the form code should update the controls.  For example:

```
public partial class Opcconnect : OPCServerClass
{
    public Tuple<string, string> DataRead()
    {
        return new Tuple<string, string>("SJZ", "TEST");
    }
}
```

(I've used a `Tuple<T1,T2>` here because without any context there's no way to know what data structure would be better appropriate.  It's likely you'd want a custom class for this.  But for now this will at least return two string values.)

Then in your form code you'd get those values and update your controls:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl,IRequireGraphicInterface
{  
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Opcconnect OC = new Opcconnect();
        var values = OC.DataRead();
        txtBox2.Text = values.Item1;
        txtBox3.Text = values.Item2;
        txtBox4.Text = "zjy";
    }
}
```

Basically, keep your UI code in the UI.  Different layers of the application (UI, business logic, database and infrastructure dependencies) shouldn't leak their implementations across layer boundaries, they should consume/return just the data being transferred.

Comment: thank you very much. your answer very useful to me. thank you.